# Spring Kafka not polling again even though commit is not executed inside the loop

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

My application works fine for the below code when start my application in debug mode but when I run my application it never goes into the loop. Even though the current timestamp becomes greater than ts2 it never goes into the loop.

```
@KafkaListener( id ="consumerContainer", topics = "topic1", groupId = "Consumer_Test", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {

           Long ts1 = record.timestamp();
           Long ts2 = ts1 + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5);
           Long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
           int b3 = currentDateTime.compareTo(ts2);
           
              if (b3 > 0) {
               this.recordPublisher.publish(record.value());
               acknowledgment.acknowledge();
               System.out.println("record received is "+record.key());
           }
    }
```

Also my factory config is :

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
```

Comment: What do you mean by debug mode? Do you pause execution? Depending where execution is paused this might modify the value of currentDateTime so that b3 is indeed > 0.

Comment: Can you show your consumer config here.

Comment: here is the config  config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, broker);       config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,"false");       config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);       config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "300000");